# Run a file like I could in command prompt

Tags: command-line, mp3, prompt

How can I run a file like I could in command prompt?

Like say I wanna run this file

```
C:/Music/BobDylan/MrTambourineManOriginal.mp3
```

I'd first navigate using `cd` to the Bob Dylan folder, and then simply type `"MrTambourineManOriginal.mp3"` and then Windows Media Player would open and play the file for me.

Is that possible in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply type the application you wish to open the file with before the filename.

Example, if I have a song called tasty.mp3 and I use `rhythmbox`, I would do

```
rhythmbox /path/to/tasty.mp3
```

Comment: Better yet, use `xdg-open`.